# Securing Flask-Admin with Flask-HTTPAUTH

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-httpauth

So I have looked everywhere for this but I couldn't find an answer.

I have recently integrated [flask-admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to my flask application, which is already, partly secured using [flask-httpauth](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s basic authentication. I am using the @auth.verify_password decorator to verify the credentials using httpauth.

I tried following the examples about how to integrate flask-basicauth with flask-admin using custom Views but I couldn't find a method that asks for the user login as the `basic_auth.challenge()`.

So here's the question, how could I fill this custom admin view to integrate httpauth?

```
class MyAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        if not auth.current_user():
            raise AuthException('Not authenticated.')
        else:
            return True
    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        # What can I put in place of this:
        return redirect(auth.challenge())
```

Or else, what's the alternative?

Comment: if you need implement security/auth function in your already apps i suggest using [flask-security-too](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You can secure every end point based on auth variety like [http auth, token, session](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#protecting-views) using decorator @auth_required("basic", "session", "token"). And more granularly, every endpoint can restricted [based on user roles](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_security.roles_required). hopefully answer

Comment: i found more simply solution check this out https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1049

Comment: @HiroakiGenpati I am not using neither flask-login nor flask-security, but I think that's going to be the only solution.